# Need assistance on integrating servicenow to MS Teams

Tags: rest, microsoft-teams, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Can anyone please let me know the Microsoft Team API where i can POST a message from Servicenow to Microsoft Team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [Proactive messaging for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#example) and [Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-using#setting-up-a-custom-incoming-webhook) documentation. Connectors can be used to send message only in a channel.

You can also use [Create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) Graph API which creates a new chatMessage in the specified channel.